# Learning PyMySQL, Python - Tuple Error

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7, pymysql

I'm learning SQL and trying to build a script that will update a db with some basic company information.

Below is the query I've got and I'm getting

QUERY:

```
  query = "UPDATE companies SET URL = '{}', Industry = '{}', Address = '{}', City = '{}', State = '{}', Country = '{}', Type = '{}', Year_Founded = {} WHERE Name = '{}') VALUES (\'{}\',{},\'{}\',\'{}\',\'{}\',\'{}\',\'{}\',{},\'{}\')".format(URL,Industry,Address,City,State,Country,Type,Year_Founded,Company_Name)
```

ERROR:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Indices:

```
insert1(company,URL,data[1],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[7],data[0],data[9])
```

Questions:

- Is there a more elegant way to build this query?
- Is it possible to put `query` onto multiple lines? What's the best way to do that?
- I know that that index goes up to 11 values so everything should be in range, could it be because some of the values are ''? ie `['Google','google.com','','','','','','','','','','']`
- Eager to get tips on how better to construct this type of a function

Comment: You have rather more format specifiers `{}` than arguments to `format`...

Comment: I'm counting 9 and 9 but maybe I'm off

Comment: I count 18 and 9 - did you mean to escape one set of them? They should be doubled `{{}}` if so.

Comment: Wow, I guess I have no clue what I'm doing. I removed the section from VALUES to ). And it worked, Thanks!